# JAVA: Can compareTo() be invoked on objects of unknown type?

Tags: java

I have a two collections of untyped Object, and I would like to compare the objects in the collection without knowing what they are, other than that they implement Comparable.  I would like to do something like:

```
int compareThings(Object o1, Object o2) {
   if (!(o1 instanceof Comparable) || !(o2 instanceof Comparable)) {
      throw ...
   }
   if (o1.getClass() != o2.getClass()) {
      throw ...
   }
   return ((Comparable)o1).compareTo(o2);
}
```

Is this possible?  Or do I need to know what each object might be, for example:

```
int compareThings(Object o1, Object o2) {
   if (o1 instanceof T1 && o2 instanceof T1) {
      return ((T1)o1).compareTo((T1)o2);
   }
   else if (o1 instanceof T2 && o2 instanceof T2) {
      return ((T2)o1).compareTo((T2)o2);
   }
   else if (o1 instanceof T3 && o2 instanceof T3) {
      return ((T3)o1).compareTo((T3)o2);
   }
   throw ...
}
```

Comment: [`Object` has no `compareTo(Object)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), therefore you cannot call `compareTo(...)` on an object of static type `Object`.

Comment: I would read up on generics.

Comment: @Turing85, I am not calling Object.compareTo(Object), I am calling Comparable.compareTo(Object).

Comment: You can do it, using raw types (as you've done). But watch out -- if your inputs are wrong, there's no way to catch it at compile time, and the ClassCastExceptions you get might happen in surprising ways. Generics hide a lot of casting behind the scene, and it won't always be where you "expect" it to be.

Comment: @yshavit, I do check for o1.getClass() == o2.getClass().  If they are not the same I will throw my own exception.  Is this sufficient?

Comment: @Wheezil you could define your method as `public static <T> int compareThings(Comparable<T> lhs, Comparable<T> rhs)`. With this, you can neglect the `instanceof` checks and everything else should be handled by the `compareTo(...)` implementation of the objects.

Comment: @Turing85, yes true the arguments could be Comparable, but that makes the caller cast the arguments from Object to Comparable.  Objects coming out of the collections are heterogeneous.  I don't want a generic cast exception in this case I would prefer to issue a more specific error message.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I would be careful about that `class !=` check. Make sure that you don't want to compare anything like a superclass and a subclass object, where you may have defined a legitimate way to compare the two in superclass. The `!=` check will throw whatever exception you had planned here, even though you may not want it too. As @Turing85 says, this might be an example of something you instead will want to handle in the compareTo() method.

Comment: (if you absolutely need a more specific error message, I mean). Otherwise, I would just let ClassCast get thrown.

Comment: You could incorporate the method equals from Object into your own method.

Comment: @Wheezil I missed that part of it. Yeah, I think you should be okay then.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder, is there a better check, like "o1's class is convertiable to o2's or vice-versa"?